# vagrant up or reload error,await_response_state

Tags: vagrant

I got this error yesterday, that's suddenly, i just upgraded my node js version from 6.9 to 8.4 in virtual machine, don't know how to resolve it.

Vagrant version `Vagrant 1.8.7`

Host operating system is `win10`

virtual machine operating system `CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)`

This is my Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "CentOS-7-Vagrant-1505-x86_64-01"


   config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.33.10"


  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/home/vagrant/sync", type: "virtualbox"
  config.vm.synced_folder "../project", "/home/vagrant/project", type: "virtualbox"

    config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
  SHELL
end
```

And this is latest output, up or reload can't be done

```
c:\www\htdocs\vagrant>vagrant reload
==> default: Attempting graceful shutdown of VM...
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
    default: The guest additions on this VM do not match the installed version of
    default: VirtualBox! In most cases this is fine, but in rare cases it can
    default: prevent things such as shared folders from working properly. If you see
    default: shared folder errors, please make sure the guest additions within the
    default: virtual machine match the version of VirtualBox you have installed on
    default: your host and reload your VM.
    default:
    default: Guest Additions Version: 4.3.14
    default: VirtualBox Version: 5.0
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-scp-1.1.2/lib/net/scp.rb:392:in `await_response_state': scp: /tmp/vagrant-network-entry-eth1-1505353872-0: No space left on device (RuntimeError)
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-scp-1.1.2/lib/net/scp.rb:363:in `block (3 levels) in start_command'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:324:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:324:in `process'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:223:in `block in preprocess'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:223:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:223:in `preprocess'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:206:in `process'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `block in loop'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `loop'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/session.rb:170:in `loop'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-ssh-3.0.2/lib/net/ssh/connection/channel.rb:269:in `wait'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/net-scp-1.1.2/lib/net/scp.rb:279:in `upload!'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:275:in `block in upload'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:654:in `block in scp_connect'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:316:in `connect'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:652:in `scp_connect'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/communicators/ssh/communicator.rb:269:in `upload'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/guests/redhat/cap/configure_networks.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in configure_networks'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.2.0/tempfile.rb:319:in `open'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/guests/redhat/cap/configure_networks.rb:29:in `block in configure_networks'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/guests/redhat/cap/configure_networks.rb:19:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/guests/redhat/cap/configure_networks.rb:19:in `with_index'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/guests/redhat/cap/configure_networks.rb:19:in `configure_networks'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/capability_host.rb:111:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/capability_host.rb:111:in `capability'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/guest.rb:43:in `capability'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/network.rb:133:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_network_interfaces.rb:26:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_settings.rb:18:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folders.rb:87:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/synced_folder_cleanup.rb:28:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/synced_folders/nfs/action_cleanup.rb:19:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_valid_ids.rb:12:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:49:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/provision.rb:80:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:15:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:19:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/box_check_outdated.rb:36:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/forced_halt.rb:20:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/discard_state.rb:15:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builtin/call.rb:53:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/providers/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/warden.rb:34:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/builder.rb:116:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `block in run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/util/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/action/runner.rb:66:in `run'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:225:in `action_raw'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:200:in `block in action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:567:in `lock'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `call'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:186:in `action'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/commands/reload/command.rb:39:in `block in execute'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:235:in `block in with_target_vms'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:229:in `each'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/plugin/v2/command.rb:229:in `with_target_vms'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/plugins/commands/reload/command.rb:37:in `execute'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/cli.rb:42:in `execute'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/lib/vagrant/environment.rb:308:in `cli'
    from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.8.7/bin/vagrant:189:in `<main>'
```

plugin is still

```
c:\www\htdocs\vagrant>vagrant plugin list
vagrant-share (1.1.5, system)
```

Comment: _No space left on device (RuntimeError)_ means you either do not have enough hard drive space left on your host machine or the VM. please confirm if you have any space left on the host machine